# How to disable camel casing Elasticsearch field names in NEST?

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

By default, NEST will camel case object and property names when sending an object to Elasticsearch for indexing. How can camel casing field names be disabled in NEST for Elasticsearch documents? I've done a fair amount of research and there's a [mailing list thread](http://elasticsearch-users.115913.n3.nabble.com/lowercase-property-names-from-NET-using-NEST-td4039978.html) on the subject, but it seems outdated as some of the methods have been renamed or no longer exist.

```
IConnectionPool connectionPool = new SniffingConnectionPool(m_ElasticsearchNodeUris);
ConnectionSettings settings = new ConnectionSettings(connectionPool);
settings.SetDefaultTypeNameInferrer(p => p.Name); //This disables camel casing for object type names
ElasticClient client = new ElasticClient(settings);
```

The info in the mailing list indicates this code should be added to handle things for field names, but the client method doesn't seem to exist:

```
client.ModifyJsonSerializationSettings(s => s.ContractResolver = new Nest.Resolvers.ElasticResolver(settings);
```

Does anyone have any updated syntax to handle this? Thanks.

Comment: how are you wanting the `Name` to come across..? `UpperCase, LosweCase..?` please clarify.. if either can't you use the `.ToUpper() or ToLower()` for example

Comment: @DJKRAZE: I don't want to modify the name at all. When I send an object to be indexed, I want the property names of the object to be unmolested. Note: settings.SetDefaultTypeNameInferrer only affects the object type (which is often inferred to be the Elasticsearch document type if you don't override it with something else more specific when you build your request). That line of code has no bearing on the property names of the object.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`ConnectionSettings.SetDefaultPropertyNameInferrer()` is what you're looking for.  This method accepts a function that takes a property name and applies a transformation to it.  The function is then called on each of your properties before requests are sent to Elasticsearch.

If you want to keep your property names untouched, then you can do this:

`settings.SetDefaultPropertyNameInferrer(p => p)`

`p => p` here just simply being a function that takes a string (your property name) and returns the same string unmodified.

Comment: Excellent. So `settings.SetDefaultTypeNameInferrer(p => p.Name);` and `settings.SetDefaultPropertyNameInferrer(p => p);` will disable camel casing for the entire object (which would be the type and field names in Elasticsearch)?

Answer (score 20):

In version 2.5.0 it's:

```
settings.DefaultFieldNameInferrer(p => p)
```

Comment: Shame on NEST!!! Shame on Elasticsearch ... I wasted 2 hours of my time to find this case. It should be set as default.

Comment: amen to the above comment - except thanks to this stack question, I solved mine in 1 minute :-)

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me as well. We had an existing ES Index with all properties lowercase. But in C#, I didn't wanted to create properties with all lowercase.