# Elasticsearch NEST library, wired behavior

Tags: .net, elasticsearch, nest

Using NEST .NET library I worte following query.

```
var result = client.Search<StudenntBrief>(s => s.Type("Students").Query(q => q.Term("Name","Robert")));
```

It worked fine and got 7 results.

Instead of using maigic string to represent field i tried to use expression as follows.

```
var result = client.Search<StudenntBrief>(s => s.Type("Students").Query(q => q.Term(t => t.Name,"Robert")));
```

I found zero results.

Here is one more example.

Works.

```
var result = client.Search<StudenntBrief>(s => s.Type("Students").Query(q => q.MultiMatch(a => a.OnFields(new List<string{"Name"}).Query("Robert"))));
```

Doesn't works.

```
var result = client.Search<StudenntBrief>(s => s.Type("Students").Query(q => q.MultiMatch(a => a.OnFields(f=> f.Name).Query("Robert"))));
```

I am wondering why query using expression to represent field is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

bsarkar's answer is partially correct.

NEST camelCases field names by default.  There are a few ways to customize this behavior.

You can override the default camelCasing by specifying your own property name inferrer: [How to disable camel casing Elasticsearch field names in NEST?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27282865/how-to-disable-camel-casing-elasticsearch-field-names-in-nest).  This approach will apply to all fields and all types.

Another approach is to specify the field names explicitly by either using the `ElasticyProperty` attribute as bsarkar mentioned, or using the newer fluent property mapping API that was added in version 1.3: https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-net/pull/1062

```
settings.MapPropertiesFor<MyClass>(props => props
    .Rename(p => p.Foo, "bar")
);
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because Nest serealizes field names to lowercase by default. Hence `t.Name` actually serializes to "name" which I guess does not exist in the mapping `Students` (Note: field names are case-sensitive in Elasticsearch) and hence no results. Whereas when you directly use "Name", it works. One way to fix this is to decorate the `Name` field in `StudenntBrief` class with attribute `[ElasticProperty(Name = "Name")]`.

Even better, you can decorate class `StudenntBrief` with attribute `[ElasticType(Name = "Students")]`. That way you can also avoid having to specify `Type` explicitly when building the search request using Nest.

Comment: Is there fluent API for doing this. I would like to keep domain class separate from underlying search technology.

Comment: If you want strongly typed field names then I guess there isn't any other way out. Why can't you have an interface like `IStudentBrief` containing the same fields and expose it? You can then make the class `StudentBrief` implement `IStudentBrief` and decorate this class with `Nest` attributes. That should solve your problem.