# NEST TermQuery for ElasticSearch not working

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

Given

```
string author = "John Smith";
```

The following lambda query using NEST works:

```
string firstname = author.Split().First().ToLower();
var searchResults = client.Search<Magazine>(s => s.From(0).Size(5000).Query(q => q.Term(p => p.Author, author)));
```

However, the same query using OIS (Object Initializer Syntax) does not work:

```
author = author.Split().First().ToLower();

QueryContainer query = new TermQuery
{
   Field = "Author",
   Value = author
};

var searchRequest = new SearchRequest
{
   From = 0,
   Size = 10,
   Query = query
};

var searchResults = client.Search<Magazine>(searchRequest);
```

What is wrong?

Comment: This should help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28312465/elasticsearch-nest-library-wired-behavior/28333375

Answer (score 0):

Try camel casing the field name:- I think this is needed when using the OIS syntax or raw query.

```
author = author.Split().First().ToLower();

QueryContainer query = new TermQuery
{
   Field = "author",
   Value = author
};

var searchRequest = new SearchRequest
{
   From = 0,
   Size = 10,
   Query = query
};

var searchResults = client.Search<Magazine>(searchRequest);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add "keyword" suffix to QueryContainer:

```
QueryContainer query = new TermQuery
{
   Field = "Author",
   Value = author
};
query.Suffix("keyword");
var searchRequest = new SearchRequest
{
   From = 0,
   Size = 10,
   Query = query
};

var searchResults = client.Search<Magazine>(searchRequest);
```

try it it will work