# Simple Existing Document Update in Elasticsearch using NEST

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

Hey I trying to update existing `document` of `ElasticSearch`, I found a `cURL` code from Elasticsearch site
Note: `Sam` type with `2` document is already exists I just want to update a existing field

```
POST /EmployeeIndex/Sam/2/_update
{
   "doc" : {
      "Nested" : true,
      "views": 0
   }
}
```

Its working perfectly how I need but please help me to convert it to `NEST`, as i working on `.NET`, I managed to write a `code`

```
 var responseUpdate = client.Update<clsEmployeeElasticSearch, object>(u => u
               .Index("EmployeeIndex")
                .Type("Sam")
                    .Id(2)
                    .Doc(new { Nested= true })
                    .RetryOnConflict(3)
                    .Refresh());
```

But it always creating a new field in my `document` instead of updating existing one.
Please see attached screenshot with a code[image]
Please help guys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need is a [`PartialUpdate`](http://nest.azurewebsites.net/nest/core/update.html). Applied on your example, the following code should do what you expect.

```
    var responseUpdate = client.Update<clsEmployeeElasticSearch, object>(u => u
         .Index("EmployeeIndex")
         .Type("Sam")
         .Id(2)
         .Doc(new {IsActive ="true", Views="0"})
         .DocAsUpsert()
     );
```

Comment: Hey @val thanx for your quick reply, I tried your code and it added `IsActive` and `views` in my `Sam` document

Comment: Which is what you expected, right? i.e. it added the fields in your Sam document with ID 2. On the next execution, it will simply update those fields.

Comment: `Sam` Type with `2` document is already exists I just want to update it @Val

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what has been updated/added then. If the document with ID 2 already exists, then it should have been simply updated. Can you show the document with ID 2, before and after runnign the code?

Comment: Oh I see "Nested" vs "nested", maybe try to write this instead `.Doc(new {"nested" = "true", "views"="0"})` or simply [disable camel-casing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27282865/how-to-disable-camel-casing-elasticsearch-field-names-in-nest)

Comment: Thanks, I'm glad you figured it out.

Answer (score 3):

Is it possible that you are already there but be just facing a casing missmatch issue? see from [Nest reference](https://nest.azurewebsites.net/nest/index-type-inference.html):

> Property Name Inference In many places NEST allows you to pass
>   property names and JSON paths as C# expressions, i.e:
>
> .Query(q=>q
>       .Term(p=>p.Followers.First().FirstName, "martijn")) NEST by default will camelCase properties. So the FirstName property above
>   will be translated to "followers.firstName".
>
> This can be configured by setting
>
> settings.SetDefaultPropertyNameInferrer(p=>p); This will leave
>   property names untouched.
>
> Properties marked with [ElasticAttibute(Name="")] or
>   [JsonProperty(Name="")] will pass the configured name verbatim.

...
Note that you are creating a dynamic object for the update so, i belive attributes might not a be a solution if you keep it that way

Comment: Thanx for brief info